# unable to access gaana api via java from mashape

Tags: spring, api, spring-security, mashape

i am trying to access gaana api from java side by using mashape api
i am trying from a localhost. but, i am getting issues while trying to connect gaana api.
Below is my code in one of my rest service ( I am using spring-security and java8). I am Btech-CSE final year student.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/ideas")
public class IdeaController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void invokeGaanaAPI() throws UnirestException {
        System.out.println("hello");
     // These code snippets use an open-source library.
//      HttpServletResponse<JsonNode> response =

        Unirest.get("https://community-gaana.p.mashape.com/index.php?subtype=most_popular&type=song")
        .header("X-Mashape-Key", "iWEvla5JyCmshafdpHdjoSdtPsHPp1Ily4qjsnCEiVxbQsY5tn")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .asJson();

        Unirest.get("https://community-gaana.p.mashape.com/user.php?type=registrationtoken")
                .header("X-Mashape-Key", "iWEvla5JyCmshafdpHdjoSdtPsHPp1Ily4qjsnCEiVxbQsY5tn")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .asJson();
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I need help to proceed in this situation.  any kind of help is fine for me. i am getting data as null. so, json conversion is throwing null pointer exception. 
I am passionate to do this project.

Comment: Well `Unirest.get` isn't assigned to anything even though you are retrieving it as a JSON.

Comment: can you please elaborate.. how to avoid it

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: my abstract of this project is, access the list of songs from gaana api for specific user. so that i can analyse and provide recommendations according to user interest.

Comment: @Geditdk your duplicate link points to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is `null` because you haven't assigned the `Unirest.get()` return value to anything.

Please read the docs on using this [API](http://unirest.io/java.html).